# Shipping charges are not displaying for Out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

we are using custom [module](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page) for displaying shipping charges in Product View page. you can download using [Magento Display shipping estimation block](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/)

its working fine for in stock products, but its not working for out of stock products :

**form.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isEnabled()): ?> 

<div class="block block-shipping-estimate" id="unique_id"> 
<img src ="http://totaltoys.com/media/font-100.png" height="35" width="70" class ="ikon"> 
<div class="block-title"> 
<strong><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getTitle(); ?></span></strong> 
</div> 

<div class="block-content"> 
<p class="block-subtitle"> 

<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getDes(); ?> 
</p> 
<ul class="shipping-estimation-form" id="shipping-estimation-form"> 
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('country')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 
<label for="estimate_country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Country') ?></label> 
<div class="input-box"> 
<?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect( 
($this->getFieldValue('country') ? $this->getFieldValue('country') : $this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry()), 
'estimate[country_id]', 
'estimate_country' 
); 
?> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php else: ?> 
<input type="hidden" id="estimate_country" name="estimate[country_id]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry())?>" /> 
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('region')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 
<label for="estimate_region_id"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label> 
<div class="input-box"> 
<select id="estimate_region_id" name="estimate[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isFieldRequired('region') ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>> 
<option value=""><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please select an option') ?></option> 
</select> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
$('estimate_region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getFieldValue('region_id')); ?>'); 
//]]> 
</script> 
<input type="text" id="estimate_region" name="estimate[region]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('region')) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" /> 
</div> 
</li> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
new RegionUpdater('estimate_country', 'estimate_region', 'estimate_region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>); 
//]]> 
</script> 
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if($this->isFieldVisible('city')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 
<label for="city"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('City') ?></label> 
<div class="input-box"> 
<input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="estimate_city" type="text" name="estimate[city]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('city')) ?>" /> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 

<label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label> 
<div class="search"> 


<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
required-entry<?php endif;?> validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits"
type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" 
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" />

</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?> 


<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('coupon_code')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 
<label for="estimate_coupon_code"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Coupon Code') ?></label> 
<div class="input-box"> 
<input class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_coupon_code" name="estimate[coupon_code]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('coupon_code')) ?>" /> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('cart')): ?> 
<li class="item radio"> 
<label for="estimate_cart_yes"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Include Cart Items') ?></label> 
<div class="input-box"> 
<input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_yes" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" <?php if ($this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Yes') ?> 
<input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_no" name="estimate[cart]" value="0" <?php if (!$this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /> <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('No') ?> 
</div> 
</li> 
<?php elseif ($this->useShoppingCart()):?> 
<input id="estimate_cart_yes" type="hidden" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" /> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</ul> 
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('shipping-estimation-form');</script> 
<div class="actions"> 
<span class="please-wait f-left" id="shipping-estimate-loading-message" style="display:none;"> 
<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?> 
</span> 
<div class="f-right"> 
<button type="button" id ="check1234" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getButton(); ?>" 
onclick="estimateProductShipping()" class="button"> 

<span><span style ="font-size:11px; padding:5px;"> 
<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('CHECK') ?></span></span> 
</button> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 

<!-- chnage 
<a id="delivery-pincode-change" href="javascript:void(0)">change</a>
change  end-->

<div id="shipping-estimate-results" style="display:none"> 
</div> 




<script type="text/javascript"> 

( function($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#estimate_postcode').keydown(function(e){ 

var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 
var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 
console.log("zipcode onkeypress worked"); 
if (!e) e = window.event; 
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
if (keyCode == '13'){ 
//disable default enter action 
e.preventDefault(); 
console.log("Enter button was pressed"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 

new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
$('#unique_id').hide(); 
//$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
}; 
}); 
}); 
} ) ( jQuery ); 

function estimateProductShipping() 
{ 

var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
'.shipping-estimation-form select', 
'#product_addtocart_form input', 
'#product_addtocart_form select']); 

var validationResult = true; 

// Check the valid input 
if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) { 
return; 
} 

var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 

$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 


new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
parameters: parameters, 
onComplete: function() { 
console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
$('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
$('shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
// $('#unique_id').hide(); 
$('unique_id').hide(); 
$('estimate_postcode').val()
} 
}); 
}

function changeEstimate(){
    $('unique_id').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
}

/* 

Event.observe('delivery-pincode-change', 'click', function(event){
$('unique_id').show();
$('shipping-estimate-results').hide();               
$('delivery-html').hide();
});

*/


/* 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('check1234').on('click', function(){ 
$('#unique_id').hide(); 
$('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
}); 
}); 

*/ 
//]]> 
</script> 



<!-- Raph --> 

<?php if ($this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode'))): ?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { 
estimateProductShipping(); 
}); 
</script> 
<?php endif; ?> 

<!-- Raph end--> 

<?php endif;?>
```

**Estimate.php**

```
<?php

class WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Estimate
{

    protected $_customer = null;


    protected $_quote = null;


    protected $_product = null;


    protected $_result = array();


    protected $_addressInfo = null;


    public function setAddressInfo($info)
    {
        $this->_addressInfo = $info;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getAddressInfo()
    {
        return $this->_addressInfo;
    }


    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->_product = $product;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_product;
    }


    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->_result;
    }


    public function estimate()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $addToCartInfo = (array) $product->getAddToCartInfo();
        $addressInfo = (array) $this->getAddressInfo();


        if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) || !$product->getId()) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please specify a valid product')
            );
        }

        if (!isset($addressInfo['country_id'])) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please specify a country')
            );
        }

        if (empty($addressInfo['cart'])) {
            $this->resetQuote();
        }

        $shippingAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

        $shippingAddress->setCountryId($addressInfo['country_id']);

        if (isset($addressInfo['region_id'])) {
            $shippingAddress->setRegionId($addressInfo['region_id']);
        }

        if (isset($addressInfo['postcode'])) {
            $shippingAddress->setPostcode($addressInfo['postcode']);
        }

        if (isset($addressInfo['region'])) {
            $shippingAddress->setRegion($addressInfo['region']);
        }

        if (isset($addressInfo['city'])) {
            $shippingAddress->setCity($addressInfo['city']);
        }

        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);

        if (isset($addressInfo['coupon_code'])) {
            $this->getQuote()->setCouponCode($addressInfo['coupon_code']);
        }

        $request = new Varien_Object($addToCartInfo);

        if ($product->getStockItem()) {
            $minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
            if($minimumQty > 0 && $request->getQty() < $minimumQty){
                $request->setQty($minimumQty);
            }
        }

        $result = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);

        if (is_string($result)) {
            Mage::throwException($result);
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                            array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));

        $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
        $this->_result = $shippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
        return $this;
    }


    public function getQuote()
    {
        if ($this->_quote === null) {
            $addressInfo = $this->getAddressInfo();
            if (!empty($addressInfo['cart'])) {
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            } else {
                $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
            }

            $this->_quote = $quote;
        }

        return $this->_quote;
    }


    public function resetQuote()
    {
        $this->getQuote()->removeAllAddresses();

        if ($this->getCustomer()) {
            $this->getQuote()->setCustomer($this->getCustomer());
        }

        return $this;
    }


    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if ($this->_customer === null) {
            $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();
            } else {
                $this->_customer = false;
            }
        }

        return $this->_customer;
    }
}
```

ex: [IN-stock](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) [Out- of -stock](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-medi-kid-8869.html) , `zip : 110001`

Comment: start by checking where `shipping is not Available` appears in the code

Comment: in database. they gave that as backend option in extension.

Comment: i am not getting even which file need to be check ?

Comment: in database find the field name, and search your code for that name.. somewhere in the extension it is saying that if products are out of stock, shipping cost will not be available

Comment: is there any way that i can find field name or manually i have to search ?

Comment: mm I don't think it's possible, the code says that the product needs to be able to add to cart.. maybe you can change it in function `estimate` in WebDevlopers/ProductPageShipping/Model/Estimate.php but I wouldn't know how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37799/discussion-between-profile-101-and-anja).

Comment: @profile101 can you jump back into chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the settings in `System > Config > Inventory`

Easiest way to do this is select all products you want to allow to be `backordered`, then select Update attributes from the actions drop down and click submit. then shipping problem will not be problem.